# Rewrite .htaccess without query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My URL Syntax Now is Like

http://20percents.com/au/restaurant/?shop=Fantasia%20MacArthur%20Central

And, how can I rewrite it to like

http://20percents.com/au/Fantasia-MacArthur-Central

Remove `restaurant` from url, remove `?shop` from url, and change the `%20` to `-`

I tried like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^restaurant/([^/\.]+)/?$ restaurant?shop=$1 [L]
```

This didn't work

I also tried like, and this too didn't work.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} val
RewriteRule ^/restaurant/?shop
```

Thanks